# Pagination woes - script working on localhost but not live

Tags: php

```
<?php



$per_page = 1;
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$totalcount = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM images");
$totalcountplus = ceil(mysql_result($totalcount, 0) / $per_page);
$totalcountone = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `images` LIMIT $start, $per_page");
while($totalcountplusone = mysql_fetch_array($totalcountone))  {
$usercountone  =$totalcountplusone['0'];
}

?>
```

Hello. I suspect this is an easy fix but im struggling to get my head around what exactly to do. For the record, this script worked perfectly on localhost, but ive since migrated to a live server.

The script is simple - it sets a number of items per page, and then causes a page break at the correct point with the LIMIT sql function. As before, this worked nicely on localhost, but since migrating it doesnt. It creates the correct number of pages, but it doesnt push the correct number of items onto each page.

I suspect its this line that is the problem:

```
$totalcountone = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `images` LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

This is evidenced by the fact that on my server notepad every other variable in the script is a dark green hue whilst $start and $per_page are both bright blue. I have tried encasing both variables within double quotes and single quotes and im not unsure as to how to fix this problem. Very frustrating.

Addition: I have just subbed the $start and $per_page for 1, 1 as integers. This still doesnt work, so im at a complete loss now, particularly as it worked on localhost. Im not sure if its the above line thats the issue now.

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: Is there data in your `images` table? if you `echo( $totalcount )` how many total records are there? I'm wondering if your script is not properly communicating with MySQL server.

Comment: @SetSailMedia yeah, the data shows fine it just doesnt paginate. as i said, i suspect this is a problem to do with the limit, which is meant to dictate that it should show $per_page, ie 1 image starting at $start of the sample, ie the first image.

Comment: @Grimbonie - you need to check the return value from your query. Is it working? Is there anything in `mysql_error()`? Have you checked that the database is set up on the live server?

Comment: @SetSailMedia ok so ive echoed out all the variables. $totalcountplus gives an answer of 3, which is correct for the number of datasets i have. interestingly when i echo out $totalcountplusone (after removing it from the while loop) it gives a literally answer of "Array". that is it...ive never seen that before. the database is absolutely fine, yes.

Comment: `$totalcountplusone` is the array result from `mysql_fetch_array()`. That's normal.

Comment: every other array ive dealt with has come back as Resource id #4 or something similar when ive echoed it. EDIT: hm long day. that would suggest it picks up an array, but that the array is empty. ok i think that narrows it down to being an issue with the line i state on its own above.

Answer (score 0):

In line

```
$totalcountplus = ceil(mysql_result($totalcount, 0) / $per_page);
```

used $per_page before it initialized

Comment: that was an edited version to try and appease the person who thought it was messy - its back as it is in my code now.